# How to show code on html with ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

i want to be able to show code on my website exactly like here on stackoverflow.
for example:

```
 public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        //TODO do something here
   }
 }
```

with highlight and colors
is there a gem for it?
i searched for a gem vut there is nothing i can find

Comment: You may Check This Link. Which has syntax highlighting
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem [coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/doc/).

As stated as-

"Fast and easy syntax highlighting for selected languages, written in Ruby. Comes with RedCloth integration and LOC counter."

Answer (score 3):

There is few gems out there:

Check [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/) for markdown.

See [pygments](http://pygments.org/) for syntax highlighting.

You can as well check a great Railscast about exactly what you are looking for [Syntax Highlighting (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting-revised)